# Setting up/troubleshooting ODBC connection for SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I've set up ODBC connections to databases before, but I'm currently having problems and can't seem to figure out what I'm missing. This isn't my area of expertise, and the Microsoft help/documentation is less than 'user friendly'. Appreciate any pointers.

I have a locally running instance of SQL Server 2014, with a couple of test databases I'm using to develop another application. Here's the info on the setup:

```
SELECT  HOST_NAME() AS 'host_name()',
@@servername AS 'ServerName\InstanceName',
SERVERPROPERTY('servername') AS 'ServerName',
SERVERPROPERTY('machinename') AS 'Windows_Name',
SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') AS 'NetBIOS_Name',
SERVERPROPERTY('instanceName') AS 'InstanceName',
SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered') AS 'IsClustered'
```

query returns:

```
host_name() ServerName\InstanceName ServerName              Windows_Name  NetBIOS_Name  InstanceName    IsClustered
DECATHLETE  DECATHLETE\SQLEXPRESS   DECATHLETE\SQLEXPRESS   DECATHLETE    DECATHLETE    SQLEXPRESS      0
```

In the Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit) - I'm running W10 in a VMWare VM on Mac, btw - the server shows up as available when I try to configure a new System DSN. Following is the setup info:

```
Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 12.00.2000

Data Source Name: TEST
Data Source Description: 
Server: DECATHLETE
Use Integrated Security: Yes
Database: (Default)
Language: (Default)
Data Encryption: No
Trust Server Certificate: No
Multiple Active Result Sets(MARS): No
Translate Character Data: Yes
Log Long Running Queries: No
Log Driver Statistics: No
Use Regional Settings: No
Use ANSI Quoted Identifiers: Yes
Use ANSI Null, Paddings and Warnings: Yes
```

Testing connectivity generates the following error message:

```
Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 12.00.2000

Running connectivity tests...

Attempting connection
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. 
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

TESTS FAILED!
```

I've confirmed access to the databases from SQL Server Management Studio. The login uses windows authentication with no password. I can get in, play with databases, run queries, etc. (See picture below).

[image]

I'm at a loss. I'd previously created ODBC connections with no problems. This seems to have cropped up as an issue since upgrading the virtual machine from W7 to W10. Hoping someone can point out an obvious oversight.

*** Update ***
Adding a screenshot of the ODBC configuration wizard below. Note that the SQL Server is showing up in the list of available servers on the wizard. So it seems to be seeing the server but failing to connect to it.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are running the SSMS "test" directly from DECATHLETE (the SQL host).  Try prefixing the "Server name:" with TCP: to force the connection over tcp (as opposed to shared memory).  ie  `tcp:DECATHLETE\SQLEXPRESS`.  Another thing to check is that the SQLBrowser service is running (since this is a named instance of SQL Server).

Comment: Do you mean in the ODBC configuration screen? There's no option to manually do that (and I've never had to do it in the past). I added a screenshot to the post above showing the setup wizard. The wizard is seeing the sql server, as it's available automatically in the pulldown list. Also, note that the server, the ODBC connection, and the application using it are all on the same box - I'm not connecting over a network.

Comment: In the ODBC dialog, "Server:" should be the name of the SQL Server instance.  You are entering `DECATHLETE\SQLExpress` in that pulldown list, right?

Comment: No. I'm simply selecting what shows on the list: "DECATHLETE" is the only thing showing. I haven't attempted to write anything.

Comment: Okay - When I manually entered 'DECATHLETE\SQLEXPRESS' as the data source, the test completed successfully, so that appears to be the problem. It's been some time since I last had to set up an ODBC connection like this, but I thought that selecting the server that showed up in the pulldown list worked fine. Apparently it needs a bit more. Do you want to post that so I can accept it as the answer? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Create a New Data Source to SQL Server" dialog/window, the incorrect "Server name:" is specified.  Since you have a named instance of SQL Server, type in the name of the SQL Server host, a backslash, and the instance name.  Here is the format:  `SQLHostName\SQLInstanceName`.

[image: "Create a New Data Source to SQL Server" dialog]

Comment: That was it, thanks. In most cases when I've had to do this, I've seen the server name in the list, and it worked fine without having to manually write it out. I was worried it might be something more complicated with the configuration and didn't think to try the simplest thing.

Answer (score 0):

Please check, whether you're allowing remote connections to the SQL Server using the 'Microsoft Sql Server 2014\Configuration Tools\Sql Server Configuration Tool' utility. 
Go to Sql Server Network Configuration and make sure you allow TCP/IP for remote connections. 
Also I'd try to play with Windows Firewall on the Sql Server PC.

Comment: Eugene - I'm not accessing it over the network. For this use case I'm accessing an instance of SQL Server running on the same machine where I am creating the ODBC connection. The application using the ODBC connection is also on that same machine. Does that make a difference? In any case, there are no items shown under the "SQL Server Network Configuration" tab on the Configuration Manager. I know that I successfully created an ODBC connection to the same database prior to the W10 upgrade, and I do not recall ever configuring any network/remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for a solution to this issue for a while now. I am trying to link SQL tables on another server to a Microsoft Access front end to make use of the Forms for data entry etc.

The comments here solved the issue and I thought I would provide a consolidated solution for clarity:

From the SQL Server Connection Manager:

1. Enable SQL Server Browser

From 'SQL Server Services', modify the Properties of the 'SQL Server Browser' and set the 'Start Mode' to 'Automatic'. Apply the changes and exit.

Start the 'SQL Server Browser'.

2. Enable TCP/IP

From 'SQL Server Network Configuration' -> 'Protocols for [your server name]', then enable TCP/IP.

Then create an ODBC connection from your local computer. From there I used the named ODBC connection in access to link the tables I needed.